# Как считать время проведенное в голосовом канале? | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть код, который реагирует на вход в голосовой, и выход из него. При входе пишется "1", при выходе "0". Как мне его изменить, чтобы он еще и считал время проведенное в голосовом канале.

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        print('1')
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
        print('0')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> считал время проведенное в голосовом канале

А в чём пробела-то ? Засепкаем время при входе, аналогично - при выходе. И берём их разницу:

```
import  time

if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
    print('1')
    t1 = time.time()
elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
    t2 = time.time()
    print('0')
    print(t2-t1)
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку при выходе из голосового канала: 

`1
0
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 163, in on_voice_state_update
    print(t2-t1)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 't1' referenced before assignment`

Comment: функция реагирует либо только на вход, либо только на выход

Comment: @VOLK -"before assignment"

- Ну значит, у Вас событие "Окончание" наступило раньше события "Начало".  Надо понимать - это начальное состояние?  Да просто перед *if* сделайте присвоение t1 = time.time() и первое значение длительности сеанса всегда будет равно 0.

Comment: @VOLK - "функция реагирует либо только на вход, либо только на выход"
- Ну это к измерению времени не имеет никакого отношения. Проблема где-то в другом месте.

Comment: Отметил Ваш ответ правильным, хотя ответил сам. Вы мне подали идею можно сказать)

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Connected')
    global tdict
    tdict = {}
    await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Game('r!help'))

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    author = member.id
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        print('1')
        t1 = time.time()
        tdict[author] = t1
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None and author in tdict:
        t2 = time.time() 
        print('0')
        print(t2-tdict[author])
```