# Время пользователя в войс канале | Discord py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы роль выдавалась через определенное время проведенное в голосовом канале, смог сделать только выдачу при подключении. Пожалуйста помогите.

Вот кусок кода:

```
if not before. channel and after.channel:
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name = "test")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1221898/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5-discord-py?rq=1
Как написано в ответах, считаете время проведённое в канале и записываете в бд. После определенного кол-ва секунд в бд можете выдать роль

Comment: @UserGames спасибо за помощь, теперь понял

Answer (score 0):

Могу рекомендовать discord py tasks, как по мне через [таски](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) сделать проще систему voice lvling

Answer (score 0):

Моя система:

Импортируем нужный модуль

```py
from discord.ext import tasks
```

Создаём словарь, в который будем писать пользователь:кол-во минут
Словарь нужен, что бы не записывать всё в бд каждую минуту, а лишь каждые 30 (Это по желанию) (У меня так-_-)

```py
user_mins = {}  # Словарь для временного хранения
elapsed_time = 0  # Счётчик времени
```

Создаём цикл, который каждую минуту проходит по всем voice каналам на сервере

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)  # Цикл считающий минуты
    async def voice_check():  # Название цикла
        global user_mins
        global elapsed_time
        for channel in client.guilds[0].voice_channels:  # По всем каналам сервера (если он один)
            # Если в канале есть кто-то и канал не afk
            if channel.members and channel.id != тут_id_akf_канала:
                for member in channel.members:  # проход по каждому пользователю в канале
                    mins = user_mins.get(member.id, 0)
                    user_mins.update({member.id: mins+1})  # обновляем словарь
        
        elapsed_time+=1  # +минута для счетчика времени
        if elapsed_time >= 30:  # Записывать данные в базу каждые 30 минут
            функция записи данных в бд
            elapsed_time = 0
```

Осталось лишь дописать запись этих данных в бд (Это уже для каждого по своему) (Тк и способы хранения данных у всех разные)
И после можно там же дописать проверку если у человека столько то часов - дать такую то роль